# Better solution for remote communication between GUI and server

Tags: c++, soap

in our company we are going to develop a server application, and a GUI which will control it. The server application is made in c++. We need to be able to send commands from the GUI to the application. They will have usually few parameters, and the data will not be very big (hardly bigger then 1kb). At first, the GUI will run on the same system of the server, but the requirement is the GUI to be placed in another machine. 
An important requirement is that while the GUI needs to send asynchronous calls to server methods, the server too must be able to send data to the GUI (for example, for reporting errors).
Right now we are evaluating the technology for the communication protocol between the GUI application and the server. We are open to various opportunities, such as SOAP, XML-RPC, JSON, Protocol buffer or others.
In the case of SOAP or similar protocols, due to the bidirectionality requirement, we could evaluate the possibility to create a polling mechanism, i.e. the GUI would periodically "ping" the server, without the need of a simmetric SOAP server, if needed.

I would like to have some suggestions regarding the various solutions available.

Update: we also need a system for authentication and encryption. HTTPS would be a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

[zeroc's ice](http://www.zeroc.com/) is also a communication middleware system worth checking, it has [bidirectional connections](http://doc.zeroc.com/display/Ice/Bidirectional+Connections) and [icestorm](http://www.zeroc.com/icestorm/index.html) has a publish/subscribe model that allows asynchronuous method invocation

Comment: We evaluated this option, but it does not seem to be widely adopted, with SOAP we would have a greater support. Also, it is not free. Did you use this system?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go with JSON.  It's a lot less verbose than XML (and by extention, SOAP), and there are plenty of libraries you can use to handle the serializing and de-serializing of the JSON data, and plenty of good tools to display JSON data in a nice way.

In my opinion, it can be just as readable to the human eye (when formatted) as XML.  And you don't have the overhead of XML, either.

Comment: We already thought about JSON, but i think SOAP is a bit more mature and widely adopted, and since we have very small amount of data, the overhead wouldn't be prohibitive. Also, something I did not mention in the question (which I'll update), we need a form of authentication and encryption, possibly out of the box.

Comment: Well, if you're going to communicate over HTTP you can still use JSON, and some kind of RESTful API.  SOAP may be more mature, but you'd be surprised how many people are using JSON over HTTP rather than SOAP.

Comment: Any thoughts regarding the bidirectional communication channel?

Comment: Well, whether you use SOAP or JSON, the transport (HTTP) is the same and so the results are the same.  As you say in your post, you can "ping" the server if you so wish.  But you don't *have* to use HTTP of course, you could just use TCP/IP, using JSON as the *format* of the messages and a library like openssl to handle the encryption.

Comment: Otherwise for a real bidirectional channel, we would need two listeners, one in the GUI and one in the server. We'll evaluate JSON for sure. So you're not suggesting other binary protocols? We had a look at Zeroc Ice too, but it does not seem so widely used.

Comment: Actually, I recommended ICE earlier on today (different forum).  For what you're doing I don't see the need of binary over "plain-text".  You said yourself the data isn't large.  For real bi-directional, yes, the GUI will connect to the server.  Once that is established they can both send/recieve to one another.  The client can then send messages (and subsequently get a response) but the server can send anything at any time to the client.  Whether that quality of service is essential for your application, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, binary or plain text makes no real difference, but while SOAP provides me with a RPC system, JSON is only a way of data coding (i.e. is somewhat the correspondent of XML in the SOAP protocol), so I would need a library in order to handle the function calls (by the way, is there some tool which creates the c++ classes from the function definitions in JSON, such as from WSDL in SOAP?).